# Create file structure based on the file date

Tags: bash, unix

I want to create a Unix script that will archive the files based on the created date of the files. If the file has a date 2020/02/03 this should automatically create a directory structure based on the file date e.g Directory will be the year 2020 within that directory should be the month and within the date/day the file was created

Comment: Standard Unix filesystems don't have a concept of *creation date*.  Sometimes people think the last inode change time is the creation date, but many actions will update that (e.g. changing permissions).

Answer (score 0):

If the date separator is not "/", then this should do the trick (in this case the date separator is "-"):

```
for foo in $(stat -c "%x" * | awk '{print $1}'); do 
  mkdir $(echo $foo | cut -d\- -f1); 
  mkdir $(echo $foo | cut -d\- -f2); 
  mkdir $(echo $foo | cut -d\- -f3); 
done
```

The "%x" in the `stat` command is to get the last access timestamp, however I think you are referring to "%w":

> %w     time of file birth, human-readable; - if unknown
>
> %x     time of last access, human-readable

Answer (score 0):

You will have to enclose the solution of Romeo Ninov below inside a loop like this:

```
for file in *; do
  date=$(stat -c "%y" "$file" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
  year=${date:0:4}
  month=${date:5:2}
  day={date:8:2}

  mkdir -p $year/$month/$day
  mv "$file" $year/$month/$day

done
```

Unlike juanp, I use the date of the last modification `%y` rather that the birth date of the file, which is not always available and probably irrelevant.